# Error when deleting Core Data object: NSManagedObjectContext cannot delete objects in other contexts

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

I am encountering an issue when attempting to remove an object from my Core Data store. The error I receive when calling `deleteOject` is as follows: `An NSManagedObjectContext cannot delete objects in other contexts.`

I have found some documentation regarding this error online but it mostly relates to accessing the ManagedObjectContext in multiple threads which can cause issues, but I am not currently working on any other threads. I have gone through my code in an attempt to ensure that I am not creating any other context except for the one that I create in my AppDelegate and can not find a likely culprit.

The code that I am testing with is below:

```
NSMutableSet *remoteNids = [NSMutableSet setWithObjects:@"140", @"141", nil];
for (GCEvent *event in nodeEventsFromStore) {
    if (![remoteNids containsObject:event]) {
        NSLog(@"Event no longer exists on remote. Removing object %@ from store.", event);
        [[delegate managedObjectContext] deleteObject:event];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Event %@ exists on remote", event);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's highly unlikely that Core Data is lying to you. I would suggest putting an assert in your code like this:

```
NSAssert([delegate managedObjectContext] == [event managedObjectContext], @"Found two contexts: %@ and %@", [delegate managedObjectContext, [event managedObjectContext]);
```

Run your app via Xcode with breakpoints on (so it breaks when you hit the assertion) and set MallocStackLoggingNoCompact=YES.

When the assert is triggered, you can use the gdb console like so:

```
(gdb) info malloc [address of event's MOC]
(gdb) info malloc [address of delegate MOC]
```

That will print the alloc stack trace and show you where you created the two moc's.

Comment: This helped me track down the problem. It was an issue with my code taking the keys of a dictionary in the for loop instead of the values. Thanks!

Comment: "It's highly unlikely that Core Data is lying to you." In fact, CoreData is lying in this case. If you pass in a non-managed object to `deleteObject:` the error is `An NSManagedObjectContext cannot delete objects in other contexts.` when really it should be something like `NSManagedObjectContext can only delete NSManagedObjects.`

Comment: If that's true you should file a bug.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to troubleshoot this would be to log the managed object context and then the `managedObjectContext` property of each `GCEvent` object before you delete it. If the error is correct the address of the two context will not match. If you don't have multiple context then the `managedObjectContext` property of each `GCEvent` is most likely `nil`.

You can get this error if you intialize a managed object directly i.e. using alloc-init, but then never assign it to the context by setting its `managedObjectContext` property to a context. A managed object context will treat any value other than itself as being another context even if that is a nil value.